# Can you escape?

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, knowledge, password

You have to find a passcode to escape from a kidnapper. Enter the right code or the room will be flooded with water. The kidnapper will give you hints, as he thinks, you are not smart enough.

Hints:

> Dej q fhydsu qdocehu.
>
> The passcode is not 2971.
>
> T3Bwb3NpdGUgb2YgcGFpeC4=
>
> SXQncyBub3QgdGhlIHllYXIsIHRoYXQgbWF0dGVycy4=
>
> 64 people are waiting in the basement.

Comment: Is the passcode necessarily a 4-digit number?

Comment: This puzzle would be easier if you were an octopus

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms If you were an octopus I'm not sure you would be very concerned about escaping a room flooding with water...

Comment: @Josh my point exactly

Comment: Oh, I thought you were trying to give a clever hint like maybe it's an 8-digit number? I think we are all collectively stuck and need another real hint.

Comment: @Josh it is, as the second hint suggested this shape.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line:

> Is encoded in caesar cipher (shifted 12 characters to the left) and it translates to "Not a prince anymore.".

The last line:

> Refers to the fact that the third and fourth line are encoded in base64

The third and fourth line translated are:

> "Opposite of paix (peace)" and "It's not the year, that matters"

Thus referring to (and leading to a possible solution of):

> The french revolution and to Louis XVII of France who was supposed to be the heir to the throne of France but was imprisoned in 1792 (see the second hind) but since it's not the year that matters the passcode could be "XVII" which is plausible if we assume that the passcode is four characters long or even better it could be "0511" if we replace the roman numerals with their first digit, therefore getting a four digit PIN code.

Comment: Congratulations, you made it! :)
By the way: The second hint was also hinting, that the code is four digits long, as it suggested a shape.

Answer (score 16):

**Incomplete answer**

> It is something to do with the French Revolution, but I'm not sure what.

Clue 1: See QuantumTwinkie's partial answer.

> "Not a prince anymore." in rot10? Is it a pun for "rotten"?

Clue 2:

> The French Revolution began in 1792, 2971 backwards

Clue 3:

> The next two lines are obviously base64-encoded and they translate to:
>  **Opposite of paix.** "Paix" is French for peace, so it would be "guerre"?
>  **It's not the year, that matters.** so the answer can't be "1792"...
>  **64 people are waiting in the basement** was probably a hint for people who didn't recognize base64 from the telltale equals-sign.

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 15):

**Partial Answer**

> If you use rot10 on *Dej q fhydsu qdocehu* you get **Not a prince anymore.** I do not yet know, what it means though.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the right path:

> As QuantumTwinkie mentioned you can decode the first line with rot10 which translates to:
>  Not a prince anymore.
>  And with the second line you get the number 2971 which you can rotate to get the year 1792 which then makes sense when you have the french word paix
>  You can guess this has something to do with French Revolution which started in 1792 but who is not a prince anymore?
>  According to the Wikipedia page of the [French Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolution):
>  `The region of modern-day Belgium was divided between two polities: the Austrian Netherlands and Prince-Bishopric of Liège.`
>  `The Liège Revolution expelled the tyrannical Prince-Bishop and installed a republic.`
>  `During the Revolutionary Wars, the French invaded and occupied the region between 1794 and 1814, a time known as the French period.`
>  `New rulers were sent in by Paris.`
>  And in the [Prince-Bishopric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince-Bishopric_of_Li%C3%A8ge) page you can find this line:
> `The role of the Bishop as prince permanently ended when the state was annexed by France in 1795.`
>  So i guess if the passcode is a 4-digit number you may insert 1795 but as it is stated that it is not the year that matters, the answer could be 'Bishop' as he was a prince but not anymore.